# Fitting curves using Gaussian, KDE or EF in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram, curve-fitting, curve

How to save a KDE curve from seaborn and use it for cross-correlation?

I have a histogram representing a pulse, and I want to use one of the before mentioned ways of fitting for it. I know you can do KDE using seaborn, but it doesn't let me save the modeled curve. I need some kind of function that lets me model these curves to make a cross-correlation with a pulses minor in size.

Is there a way to create something like that?

Comment: Hi! By KDE you mean Kernel Density Estimators? What do you mean by EF?

Comment: Yes, by KDE i mean that, and by EF i mean Empirical Fourier

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:** Neither `seaborn.kdeplot()` nor `seaborn.ecdfplot()` allow you to directly access the modeled curve which was fitted in its chart. However, using the linked codes below, it should be possible to replicate the results by running the underyling seaborn code directly.

**Kernel Density Estimation**

The `seaborn` library contains the code fitting the ´KDE´ in [`_statistics.py`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/_statistics.py#L134). In that script, the `_fit` method leverages the implementation of `scipy` as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# note: `bw_method`, `weights`, and `factor` are arguments which can be
# specified in seaborn.kdeplot()
def _fit(self, fit_data, weights=None):
    """Fit the scipy kde while adding bw_adjust logic and version check."""
    fit_kws = {"bw_method": self.bw_method}
    if weights is not None:
        fit_kws["weights"] = weights

    kde = gaussian_kde(fit_data, **fit_kws)
    kde.set_bandwidth(kde.factor * self.bw_adjust)

    return kde
```

Unfortunately, `_fit()` does not get assigned to any attribute, neither in `_statistics.py` nor in [`distributions.py`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/129ce703052ff56f27014a0d8e4e6203b531b7a8/seaborn/distributions.py#L1598) where `seaborn.kdeplot()` id defined. Therefore, **while it is not possible to directly retrieve your fitted `KDE` from a chart, the code fitting the `KDE` is quite straightforward and you can easily replicate the fitted curve using the code above directly.**

**Empirical Cumulative Distribution Functions (ECDF)**

First, I assume that by `Empirical Fourier` you meant an `ECDF`. Similar to `KDE`, the statistical code can be found in [`_statistics.py`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/_statistics.py#L401) and the implementation of `seaborn.ecdfplot()` in  [distributions.py](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/129ce703052ff56f27014a0d8e4e6203b531b7a8/seaborn/distributions.py#L1878). As before, I was not able to identify any attribute in the classes which would allow you to retrieve the information from a chart. However, **as in the case of `KDE`, the code definitions should allow you to directly replicate the empirical cumulative distribution function.** The `seaborn` code for getting the ECDF is as follows:

```
def _eval_univariate(self, x, weights):
    """Inner function for ECDF of one variable."""
    sorter = x.argsort()
    x = x[sorter]
    weights = weights[sorter]
    y = weights.cumsum()

    if self.stat in ["percent", "proportion"]:
        y = y / y.max()
    if self.stat == "percent":
        y = y * 100

    x = np.r_[-np.inf, x]
    y = np.r_[0, y]

    if self.complementary:
        y = y.max() - y

    return y, x
```